# In Makefile use environment variable defined in Docker container to run a command

Tags: shell, docker, makefile

I am trying to run a command from a docker-compose service, and I want to to use the environment variables defined in my container like this:

In my Makefile:

```
sqlcmd: 
    docker-compose run sqlcmd sqlcmd -S sqlserver -U "$SQL_HOST" -P "$SQL_PASSWORD"
```

Then I run `make sqlcmd`.

But it's printing out truncated words. What I want it to do is use the environment variables `$SQL_HOST` and `$SQL_PASSWORD`, which are defined in the container.

How do I get this to escape properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a literal $, use $$.

```
docker-compose run sqlcmd sqlcmd -S sqlserver -U "$$SQL_HOST" -P "$$SQL_PASSWORD"
```

If SQL_HOST and SQL_PASSWORD are variables defined earlier in your Makefile, (rather than environment variables) you need to write it like this:

```
SQL_HOST=localhost
SQL_PASSWORD=hunter2
sqlcmd: 
    docker-compose run sqlcmd sqlcmd -S sqlserver -U "$(SQL_HOST)" -P "$(SQL_PASSWORD)"
```

PS: Welcome to the site.

**EDIT**: To delay expansion of the variables until the container has started, you need to prevent your shell from expanding them. If a variable is enclosed in single quotes, the shell will not try to expand it.

Here's an example:

```
docker-compose run sqlcmd sqlcmd -S sqlserver -U '"$$SQL_HOST"' -P '"$$SQL_PASSWORD"'
```

**EDIT EDIT**: I guess you need this too, to tell Docker to use the shell to expand the variables:

```
docker-compose run sqlcmd sh -c 'sqlcmd -S sqlserver -U "$$SQL_HOST" -P "$$SQL_PASSWORD"'
```

Comment: Thank you!

Pretty sure I tried the double `$$`.
Getting this:
    Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login failed for user ''..
It's printing a blank string now... I need to get the environment variable defined in the container.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused. If you run a command in a Makefile, it should pass the environment variables you have defined through to the command it runs. Example: https://paste.debian.net/plainh/996f91e6 How is your environment variable defined right now?

Comment: I have the same environment variables defined on my host, but I want to use the environment variables defined in my Docker container. The host variables are defined in my bashrc file, and the environment variables in the container are defined in the docker-compose file.

Comment: Thanks for the update... still having trouble. I tried this `docker-compose run sqlcmd echo '"$SQLSRV_HOST"'`, and it's now literally printing out ``$SQLSRV_HOST`` , but I think we're getting closer...

Comment: YES! It does. Thank you so much!